# Modify theme Shopify from template html

Tags: shopify

I want to know how to modify a theme shopify from a template (html,css,bootstrap). I have list of folder that contain files of css, html and bootstrap. i need to integrate theme in shopify theme how to do it please ?

THANK you.

Answer (score 0):

**Customizing themes**

You can add custom functionality or information by editing your theme code. a Shopify theme have the extension .liquid , and are known as Liquid templates.Aside from Liquid, Shopify theme files also contain HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

read this

https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization